# (OS X)Unable to Export .p12 on Keychain

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, keychain, apn

Issues were encountered After creating both a Development SSL Certificate, as well as a Production SSL Certificate. In case you're struggling with the procedure, I found this link to be quite helpful:

[How to export certificate from Mac OS X to get pair of .cert and .key files ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238461/how-to-export-certificate-from-mac-os-x-to-get-pair-of-cert-and-key-files)

The screen shows instructions for creating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR). I Selected "Continue", then selected "Choose File..." and located the .certSigningRequest.

Selected "Generate". Once the certificate was ready, I selected "Done" and then downloaded the generated SSL certificate from the "iOS App ID Settings" screen.

Follow this link as it is pertaining to the bottleneck at hand:
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

You must Double click on the downloaded SSL certificate to install it. Using Keychain Access, click right under "My Certificates", then you must find the certificate you just added.

Right-click on it, select "Export Apple Development IOS Push Services:...", and save it as a .p12 file. The problem is, I don't have the option to export to .p12 as it is grayed out.

How should I proceed?

Comment: if you select the certificate rather than only the key, the option should be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your Keychain Access and make sure your certificate is listed under **login** keychains (left side), then you should be able to see the export to a .p12 file option. If that does not work for you, possibly your certificate is created incorrectly. Try to generate another one.

Answer (score 43):

Turns out all you have to do is select "My Certificates" on the left panel and it enables the .p12 option.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.

Comment: Good answer, does not work for every type of certificate though

Comment: "My Certificates" is along the top in 2023. Clicking that first, then clicking the cert to export enables the p12 option. FML ‍♂️ makes no sense, lol, but works.

Answer (score 1):

2021 answer

What worked for me was to open ***KeyChain Access***, under ***My Certificates*** tab, select both files, right clic, ***export 2 items***, and the option was available.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awsome. This the correct answer for 2022. Thank you very much.